# Стили TreeView в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, style, treeview

Я долго искал в интернете различные стили контрола TreeView, но не нашёл ни одного. Если кто может, скиньте стили этого элемента. Если же всё таки стилей у вас не будет, то скажите как можно реализовать и подключить свой стиль элемента. Другими словами, как его вообще делать?

Comment: В WinForms нет стилей, как таковых. Нужно либо вручную рисовать компонент в событиях `DrawNode`, `OnPaint` и т. п., либо использовать сторонние компоненты.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А есть какой-нибудь хороший гайдик по этому?

Comment: [TreeView.DrawNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode(v=vs.110).aspx).